# List SFTP Processor not picking files in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi Version- 1.7.1
List SFTP Processor doesn't lists the files when run via CRON jobs/Schedule even though the file is available.
We even see that List SFTP processor has run.
On doing a restart of process(STOP,change schedule,START) the List SFTP Processor picks up the file.
Can someone suggest on the root cause and let us know how to fix it as these were working fine before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not seeing any failure messages in *nifi-app.log* and your *path* parameter is configured correctly.

I suggest you verify the *Listing Strategy* field of [*ListSFTP*](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/) processor

- **Tracking Timestamps (default)** - Track's the latest timestamp, can be inaccurate in some situations as it ignores files that were changed with earlier timestamps than the latest.
- **Tracking Entities** - Tracks additional params such as file size to avoid missing changes in previous strategy, trades off for more heap memory required to keep all the info and more configs (Entity Tracking State Cache, Entity Tracking Time Window).
- **No Tracking** - Will grab all available files each iteration (no state).
- **Time Window** - Track only files with modification time between last run and current run, ignores all other files (time needs to be synched with SFTP server).

If you just wan't to grab the file name no matter what you can change *Listing Strategy* to *No Tracking*.

If these are special files (such as hidden files) there are more config options to change the default tracking behavior, but would have to ask you for more details :)

Hopes this helps